# running raw SQL but return array of model instances

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I would like to run a sql statement, and have the return value be an array of models, presently an array of stdClass is been returned.

I am doing something like this

```
DB::select('some sql statement')
```

the return result is something like

```
array(2) {
  [0]=> object(stdClass)#524 (7) .....
  [1]=> object(stdClass)#525 (7) .....
```

I would rather

```
array(2) {
  [0]=> object(App\Feed)#524 (7) .....
  [1]=> object(App\Feed)#525 (7) .....
```

The query only involves a single table (no joins etc). Code would look a lot more messy if I was to use query builder with `DB::raw()` etc. I understand risks of SQL injection.

Is there a suitable way to do this?

Model code (Feed.php)

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Feed extends Model
{
    .......
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep it simple :) 
http://commandz.io/create-models-from-query-builder/

```
    $result = Feeds::query()
                ->where(
                    ['wait_seconds', '>', 'TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, emailed_at, NOW() )'],
                    ['GREATEST(wait_seconds / 6, '.self::MIN_RESCAN_SECONDS.')', '>', 'TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, scanned_at, NOW() )']
                )
               ->orWhereNull('scanned_at')
               ->get();;
    $feeds = \App\Feed::hydrate($result);
```

Comment: the actual query I would like to run is

`SELECT * 
      FROM feeds WHERE
       (
        wait_seconds > TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `emailed_at`, NOW() ) AND
        GREATEST(wait_seconds / 6, '.self::MIN_RESCAN_SECONDS.') > TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `scanned_at`, NOW() )
       )
       OR 
       (
        scanned_at IS NULL
       )`

It seemed much more messy using multiple where() and DB::raw()

Comment: could `Feed::query($sql)->get();` be what I am looking for?

Comment: That is what i changed the answer too! :) but I used the query builder for the sql....

Answer (score 1):

In this case you should use Models - https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent